# Getting primary key in C# of row that is being deleted using gridview delete functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using a SQLDataSource connected to a gridview.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [NonScrumStory].[IncidentNumber], [NonScrumStory].[Description], [NonScrumStory].[CreatedDate], [DailyTaskHours].[Hours], [Application].[AppName], [SupportCatagory].[Catagory] FROM [NonScrumStory], [DailyTaskHours], [Application], [SupportCatagory] WHERE ([NonScrumStory].[UserId] = @userIdSelected) AND ([NonScrumStory].[PK_NonScrumStory] = [DailyTaskHours].[NonScrumStoryId]) AND ([NonScrumStory].[CatagoryId] = [SupportCatagory].[PK_SupportCatagory]) AND ([NonScrumStory].[ApplicationId] = [Application].[PK_Application])"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DailyTaskHours] WHERE PK_DailyTaskHours = @test">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userIdSelected" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="test" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image]

When I press a delete button for a specific row. How I get that rows primary key in C# before it is deleted? Note that this row is populated from two different tables, although getting the primary key of either will be fine.

Comment: I would really recommend taking this time to work on separating the "DAL" from the view. Now, I *know* that the SqlDataSource Control and similar shipped from MSFT - but it really makes code brittle, spreads out logic (or lack thereof) everywhere, and effectively ensures the solution is not testable. Switching to a proper DAL/BL (which can be exposed by [GenericDataSource](http://genericdatasource.codeplex.com/) flexibly) may be beneficial as the project grows ..

Answer (score 0):

Consume the [`Deleting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deleted.aspx) event of the `SqlDataSource`. Once in that event you'll be able to access the current row against the `GridView` like this:

```
gridView.SelectedRow ...
```

and grab whatever you need.